# Configure fingerprint-gui so that it does not ask for fingprint authentification on sudo

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I find the dialog that pops up extremely annoying as I find it more convenient to type out the password. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can by done by editing `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and deleting the line permitting usage of `fingerprint-gui`:

```
auth        sufficient  pam_fingerprint-gui.so
```

This command will do that:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/fingerprint-gui/d' /etc/pam.d/sudo
```